# linux route nic2 connections to nic1

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, routing, forwarding

I have in linux envrioment:

> 1) firewall (192.168.1.1)
>
> 2) server1 (192.168.1.2)
>
> 3) server2 ubuntu
>   (NIC1 - 192.168.1.3 - NIC2 - 192.168.2.1 - can customize)
>
> 4) device1 -
>   192.168.2.2  - can customize
>
> 5) client (192.168.1.4)

I can acccess from client all thins except device1, 
serer2 can access device1

how I can confgure server2 to route nic2 traffic in same subnet and access it from client?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ip route add` command. The man page, many posts on this site and on other sites, will give you numerous examples.

```
# ip route add 10.200.6.0/24 dev eth1 src 10.200.6.55 table eth1
# ip route add default via 10.200.6.203 dev eth1 table eth1
```

http://brainscraps.wikia.com/wiki/Setup_Gateway_Routing_On_Multiple_Network_Interfaces